# Why is SSE smaller for a "full" multi-regression model than for a "reduced" multi-regression model?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

We're learning about multi regression in the current module of my statistics course, and the instructor noted that the sum of square errors (SSE) of a full model such as the one below:

$Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{1i}+\beta_2x_{2i}+\beta_3x_{3i}+\epsilon_i$

is going to be smaller than the SSE for any reduced model, such as the one below (which we obtain under the assumption that $\beta_1=0$):

$Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_2x_{2i}+\beta_3x_{3i}+\epsilon_i$

I'm having trouble understanding why this is true. If SSE is defined as:

$\sum^{n}_{i=1}(y_i-\hat{y_i})$

Shouldn't the full model's SSE be bigger because it has more terms?

Comment: I think that by "multi regression", you mean "multiple regression" (which is different from "multivariate regression", so it's worth writing the extra syllable).

Comment: Note that the number of terms doesn't show up in your $\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat{y}_i)$. The only issue is how close you can get $\hat{y}_i$ to $y_i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\beta_1$ is exactly zero, the SSE for full and reduced models will be identical. To the extent $\beta_1$ is *not* exactly zero, the component of the variance (sums of squares) of *Y* attributable to $x_1$ is added to the SSE, all else being equal, as it is no longer represented in the model anywhere but *e* (the residual variance).

So the SSE for a reduced model can never be smaller than the SSE for a full model, because it's the SSE for the full model *plus* any SS attributable to the constraints to the extent they are something other than exactly true.